# Finding function $f(x,y)$ and $\varphi (x)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to learn functions of multiple variables and currently trying to solve the following problem:

Find the functions $f(x,y)$ and $\varphi (x)$, if $f(x,y) = x-y + \varphi(x+y)$ and $f(x,0)=x^3$.

Could you help me how to start?

This is my first problem regarding functions with multiple variables and I am clueless.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $ f(x,0) = x^3$, we can put $y = 0$ into the definition for $f(x,y)$ to obtain $$ f(x,0) = x - 0 +\varphi ( x + 0) $$ ie $ \varphi (x) = x - f(x,0) = x - x^3$.

Then find $\varphi (x + y) $ and substitute it in to find $ f(x) $.

Comment: Could you tell me how to find $\varphi (x+y)$?

Comment: Substitute $x+y$ in for '$x$' - the variable $x$ in $\varphi (x) $  is just a placeholder to define the function, you could instead have defined $\varphi (X) = ...$ and set $X = x+y$. So $\varphi ( x+y) = (x+y) - (x+y)^3$